# Recursive chmod fails

Tags: macos, terminal, permission

I have a folder owned by `root:admin`. I would like to change permissions of all files inside, so I can edit them without `sudo`, but recursive chmod fails:

```
$ sudo chmod -R u+w some-folder/
```

does nothing. Any ideas how to fix it?

At the same time changing permission to a single file works seamlessly.

Story:

I installed a Python package from GitHub repository via `pip`, as an editable install. I am contributing some changes to it, but doing `sudo` for every edit and every `git` command is not convenient (I guess - neither safe).

EDIT:

```
$ sudo chmod -v -R u+w some-folder/
```

returns nothing.

Path is below:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/
```

Comment: You likely want to edit `o` other permissions and not `u` user (owner) permissions. Any symlinks in the folder? By default `chmod -R` does not follow them.

Comment: @laalto No symlinks. I do want `u` permissions (for a file I changed it with `u+w` I can edit it without `sudo`).

Comment: Can you please run `sudo chmod -v -R u+w some-folder/` and *edit* the result into the question?

Comment: What are the permissions and owner of the files? e.g. ls -l on the files

Comment: @patrix I did it before. And there is no output of any kind.

Comment: @Mark Permissions - various (from `drwxr-xr-x` to the most common `-rw-r--r--`). Owner, as I already wrote `root  admin`.

Comment: Please run `ls -ld /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages` and add the output to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that to be able to write to a file you need to be the owner for u permissions or be part of the group for g.

Note as a user you are not root so if owned by root the u permission does not matter. As you are using sudo I assume you are in the admin group (this is not necessarily the case but if anyone  alters this I would expect they fully understand these permissions). These files are owned by admin so the permission that matters is the g one.

Thus the chomd you need is

```
sudo chmod -v -R g+w some-folder/
```

There are alternatives

1. As this is where python is installed you should be using pip, easy_install and setuptools to do these updates which will require sudo. Another way is to use virtualenv and so install will be done to your own directories
2. You can change the owner
   `sudo chown -R user some-folder/`